# Neo4j - Remove nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j database there are some nodes with the *ref* field with the value equal to the *id* field that is present in other nodes.
In other words, it's an XML file with some nodes that reference other nodes.
Is there a way to remove these nodes?

Comment: You are trying to remove a set of nodes which the `ref` property is equal to one `id` of another set of nodes, right?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand, you are trying to remove a set of nodes which the value of `ref` property is equal to one of the `id` property of another set of nodes. If so you can do it using a Cypher query like this:

```
match (n1:Node)
// store all ids into a collection called 'ids'
with collect(distinct n1.id) as ids

// match all nodes that 'ref' property equal to any value in 'ids' 
match (n2:Node)
where n2.ref in ids

// delete all n2 nodes and its relationships
detach delete n2
```